# How to conditionally apply ng-disabled bassed on attribute?

Tags: angularjs

For example, I have this:

```
<button ng-disabled="profile.isLoading || profile.isEmpty" ng-click="profile.saveProfile()"></button>
```

I would like to conditionally apply profile.isEmpty based on a new attribute in my profile directive that takes the value of a cookie, say profile.isNewProfile. Initially I thought I could utilize a ternary operator like

```
<button ng-disabled="profile.isLoading || (profile.isNewProfile ? "" : "profile.isEmpty"">
```

but that only seems to work for classes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes and empty is set if `newprofile` is available else `isempty` is set.

```
<button ng-disabled="profile.isLoading || (profile.isNewProfile ? '' : profile.isEmpty)">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like I actually just needed to remove the quotes.